# Url rewrite domain name

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

I am hosting an asp.net core web site which can be accessed via an ip address. Users of myexampledomain.co.uk are directed to this site, but I want it to appear as if the user is still on the same domain by rewriting the ip address 49.56.17.143:7062 in the address bar to https://myexampledomain.co.uk/

The rule I have is below but is not working

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="SearchIrlRewrite">
             <match url="http://49.56.17.143:7062/" />
             <action type="Rewrite" url="https://myexampledomain.co.uk/" />
         </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Mistake 1 in https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0):

The url in the match tag should match what comes after your hostname, Here is a case you can use as a reference:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
       <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="49.56.17.143:7062" />
       </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://myexampledomain.co.uk" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```